# Why i see a property data traffic in all properties on GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have 6 properties in same ga4 account. I made installation GTM and put into the site. But just one property's data traffic like page-view appears in all properties reports. There was filter for this in GAU but i can't find in GA4. First of all i added new domain in data flow tab but it doesn't work so i create new properties and again it doesn't work. How can i solve this please help. Why do I see data traffic from other properties in google analytics account even though I created all properties separately. Could it have something to do with the fact that I use the same gtm account?

Comment: Do you mean you have 6 data streams tied to the same property? Or 6 different properties? If you have 6 separate streams and you are using one GTM container, you need to make sure you have a dedicated config tag for each stream. Then you will need to trigger those separately for the specific domains you are looking to segment. I believe this isn't the best practice, but to have a single stream for all your web traffic. Then you can create segments/audiences based on which site they are on.